# Dynamically Creating Image - Does not Exist in Current Context

Tags: c#, image

I am trying to create a WhackaMole game in WPF in C#. I am a bit of a noob. In the for loop I am trying to add the number of "i" to the "Image". I get the following error:

```
 "Error The name 'Image1' does not exist in the current context"
```

same thing for 'Image2' and so on. I am trying to integrate the images into a StackPanel.

Thanks for the help :)

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Image[] ImageArray = new Image[50];
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Moleini = MoleScore[1];
            InitializeComponent();
            //string ImageName = "Image";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
            {
                Image Image = new Image();
                ImageArray[i] = Image;
                Image.Name = "Image" + i.ToString();
            }

            ////Create Images
            //for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
            //{
            //    StackPanel1.Children.Add(CreateImage(i));
            //}

            //Dispacher for Mole to Appear
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();

            //Dispacher for Full Game Time
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer endGame = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            endGame.Tick += new EventHandler(endGame_Tick);
            endGame.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            endGame.Start();
        }

        ////Create Image
        //public Image CreateImage(int i)
        //{

        //}

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Random Number Generator
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int num = rnd.Next(1, 9);

            //If Random Number is "1" Then Image will display
            if (num == 1)
            {
                ImageSource MoleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgNameMole));
                Image1.Source = MoleImage;            
            }
            //If Random Number does not equal 1
            if (num != 1)
            {
                ImageSource hole = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgHole));
                Image1.Source = hole;
            }

            //If Random Number is "2" Then Image will display
            if (num == 2)
            {
                ImageSource MoleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgNameMole));
                Image2.Source = MoleImage;
            }
}
```

Comment: if (num == 2) will never hit cause u check before num != 1 which will be true or num==1

Comment: I have several more if (num == x) statements, that is just saying to display other image using a random number generated.

Comment: you semantic is wrong.. you need to do it like if(num == 1) { ... } else if(num == 2) { ... } ect.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: What is ImageArray & where/how do you initialize it?

Comment: It is stated before,

Image[] ImageArray = new Image[50];

Comment: I just added it to the main code in the question :)

Comment: What is ImgNameMole? Where/to what is it set?

Comment: static String ImgNameMole = "C:/Users/MonAmi/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/WhackaMole/Hammer/Mole-with-Shovel.jpg";

static String ImgHole = "C:/Users/MonAmi/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/WhackaMole/WhackaMole/hole.jpg";

Comment: I believe in `dispatcherTimer_Tick` you want `Image[1]` instead of `Image1`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: Sorry, `ImageArray[1]` instead of `Image1`.

Comment: What exactly is the line that it crashes on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this updated code:

```
            private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Random Number Generator
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int num = rnd.Next(1, 9);

                //If Random Number is "1" Then Image will display
                if (num == 1)
                {
                    ImageSource MoleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgNameMole));
                    ImageArray[1].Source = MoleImage;            
                }
                //If Random Number does not equal 1
                if (num != 1)
                {
                    ImageSource hole = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgHole));
                    ImageArray[1].Source = hole;
                }

                //If Random Number is "2" Then Image will display
                if (num == 2)
                {
                    ImageSource MoleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgNameMole));
                    ImageArray[2].Source = MoleImage;
                }
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU! FINALLY GOT THIS WORKING! :D

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using the MVVM design pattern for your game? It's better suited to WPF's technology as it keeps the data and UI layer separate, like WPF's XAML and Binding system does, and it would make this much easier.

I remember [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13588066/302677) a similar question about a minesweeper game, so I'll start there.

Begin with creating your `Mole` objects. Moles have 3 properties: `RowIndex`, `ColumnIndex`, and `IsUp` property.

Now you need a template to draw your `Mole` objects. Create a `DataTemplate` for the `local:Mole` object, and draw it using your images. A `DataTrigger` can be used to draw a mole picture if `IsUp=True`, or a hole image if `IsUp=False`.

Now in your code-behind, create a list of `Mole` objects, and initialize their default values. This just means two loops that go through creating `Mole` objects, and setting their Row/Column index.

To draw the list, use an `ItemsControl` in XAML. Change the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `Grid`, and bind the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties of the `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` to the `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` properties on your `Mole` object.

And last of all, start up a timer that randomly changes the `IsUp` property of of a random `Mole` object in the list with `IsUp=false` to `true`. When changing it to true, also kick off a 2nd timer that will change `IsUp=false` after a random amount of time.

Adding score should be fairly easy. Add a `ICommand HitMoleCommand` to the `Mole` object, which returns a `RelayCommand` that is enabled when `IsUp=True`, and do some logic there (calculate points, change `IsUp=False` and cancel timer, etc).

But anyways, `Image1` is not a property of your `MainWindow` class, which is why you can't access it from your dispatcher code. Just creating an object and giving it a name does not store it as a property on the Window, like when you create an object and give it a name in the XAML before running the project. You need to store the image somewhere on the class to access it like that, such as in the `ImageArray` object.

And I see that you've found your answer in the time it took me to write this, but I'm posting it anyways because I strongly feel that if you're working with WPF, you really should at the very least understand the MVVM design pattern, even if you don't choose to use it :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have omitted code, `Image1` and `Image2` have not been previously declared. Using these variables within the context of `dispatcherTimer_Tick` scope will result in a compile-time error.

I think you intended to reference the `ImageArray` instead.

```
// instead of this
Image1.Source = MoleImage;
// you want this
ImageArray[1].Source = MoleImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image Image = new Image();`  will probably lead to problem. You should consider using `Image image = new Image();`  , without the capital I on the variable name

Comment: It is absolutely no harm the way we declare a variable in C#, the compiler can distinguish it properly. But from coding guidelines point it is not a Best practice.